# How to read specific lines from file and store in an array using perl?

Tags: perl

How can i read/store uncommented lines from file into an array ?

`file.txt` looks like below

```
request abcd uniquename "zxsder,azxdfgt"
request abcd uniquename1 "nbgfdcbv.bbhgfrtyujk"
request abcd uniquename2 "nbcvdferr,nscdfertrgr"
#request abcd uniquename3 "kdgetgsvs,jdgdvnhur"
#request abcd uniquename4 "hvgsfeyeuee,bccafaderryrun"
#request abcd uniquename5 "bccsfeueiew,bdvdfacxsfeyeueiei"
```

Now i have to read/store the uncommented lines (first 3 lines in this script) into an array. is it possible to use it by pattern matching with string name or any regex ? if so, how can i do this ?

This below code stores all the lines into an array.

```
open (F, "test.txt") || die "Could not open test.txt: $!\n"; 
@test = <F>; 
close F; 
print @test;
```

how can i do it for only uncommented lines ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know your comments will contain # at the beginning you can use

```
next if $_ =~ m/^#/
```

Or use whatever variable you have to read each line instead of `$_`

This matches # signs at the beginning of the line.
As far as adding the others to an array you can use `push (@arr, $_)`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Should always include these
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines; # Hold the lines you want

open (my $file, '<', 'test.txt') or die $!; # Open the file for reading
while (my $line = <$file>)
{
  next if $line =~ m/^#/; # Look at each line and if if isn't a comment
  push (@lines, $line);   # we will add it to the array.
}
close $file;

foreach (@lines) # Print the values that we got
{
  print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: @ squiguy : if this code read all the lines of a file how can i read the uncommented lines ?
open (F, "test.txt") || die "Could not open test.txt: $!\n";
@test = <F>;
close F;
print @test;

Comment: I'll update my answer to how I would do what you need to for the whole script.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
push @ary,$_ unless /^#/;END{print join "\n",@ary}'
```

This skips any line that begins with `#`.  Otherwise the line is added to an array for later use.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest change to your original program would probably be:

```
open (F, "test.txt") || die "Could not open test.txt: $!\n"; 
@test = grep { $_ !~ /^#/ } <F>; 
close F; 
print @test;
```

But I'd highly recommend rewriting that slightly to use current best practices.

```
# Safety net
use strict;
use warnings;
# Lexical filehandle, three-arg open
open (my $fh, '<', 'test.txt') || die "Could not open test.txt: $!\n"; 
# Declare @test.
# Don't explicitly close filehandle (closed automatically as $fh goes out of scope)
my @test = grep { $_ !~ /^#/ } <$fh>; 
print @test;
```